# Specify location of generated "ui_" file in qt designer

Tags: qt-creator, projects-and-solutions, qt-designer

Is there any way to specify in Qt Creator / Designer where to save the auto-generated "ui_" files?

I've set up a project structure with subdirectories and it's strange to have this type of code:

```
#include some/subdir/myform.h
#include ui_myform.h
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify it in the UI_DIR directive in your .pro .
You'll find more about this here : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qmake-variable-reference.html#ui-dir